# What is the *right* way to save complex user data in Windows Store App development?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-runtime, windows-8.1

I am learning Windows Store App development. I am an iOS developer with a lot of Cocoa Touch experience, but no Microsoft technology experience, so everything from the language to the tools is new to me.

I can't figure out what the *right* way to save complex user data is in Windows Store Apps. The way I have always handled saving user data in iOS is by having a class (or series of classes) that represent my App's data model that I serialize and deserialize (with NSCoder / encodeWithCoder / decodeWithCoder) for the purpose of saving. I assumed that's what I'd do on Windows Store apps, but after hours of research and trial and error (mostly error) I'm thinking that's not how things are done in this world.

Here's my use case: I'm writing a simple image processing / collage app that allows users to import photos, arrange and process them, and then save or share the output. My data model is a class that manages an array of Images. The properties of the Images reflect their positions, transformations, etc.

To allow my users to save and load their creations I figured I would simply serialize and deserialize my data model class. However, it seems that Windows Store apps only have XMLSerializer, and it is extremely limited. You can't serialize images, never mind arrays of images. On top of that it seems to require lots of plumbing code that I can't find examples of to even work for custom classes. You could serialize a string with it, but anything more complex seems out of the picture.

So, Windows developers, what is the right way to do this? Should I copy all of the files for a given collage, put them in a directory, save a manifest of what files are displayed where, compress that, and call that my file? That seems like a *lot* of work. Have I been remiss in my research? Is there a simple way to binary-serialize my data model like I could on iOS?

Thanks *very much* for help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to serialize an object model, but the one I use is [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

It works as you described, you write some classes, add attributes for serialization to them and then simply serialize them with `DataContractSerializer`.

Images are not serialized by it, you have to take care of that yourself.

Comment: Thanks. I marked as "answered" because this does appear to be the Windows way of doing things, but it isn't comparable to NSCoder on iOS. Having to take care of the images myself sucks. I just want my entire object serialized, I don't want to muck about with the details. Thanks though, I appreciate the reply.

Comment: i feel your pain, as I made a collage app myself (called phototastic) and had the very same problem...

Answer (score 1):

Using either DataContractSerializer or SQLite.

You can find useful information here:
http://irisclasson.com/2012/07/11/example-metro-app-winrt-serializing-and-deseralizing-objects-using-xmlserializer-to-storagefile-and-localfolder-using-generics-and-asyncawait-threading/

or

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Sqlite-For-Windows-8-Metro-2ec7a882